# Accessing XBMC Home.xml remotely

Tags: xbmc

Is it possible for XBMC to call its Home.xml externally? i.e. not from its 720p directory?

Or which file is in charge for keeping all the paths?

I am asking this because I have multiple fedora-based systems that uses XBMC. This systems are placed very far from where I am so I cannot physically be next to the system.

I was wondering if I can keep every Home.xml on my server so that I can just configure it from my server so I dont have to go to my system to change it.

I guess the better question is, How can I change Home.xml remotely? 
I dont have ssh access to the system because the system is inside the internal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are as follows

1. Use dropbox. Edit your copy, then let dropbox on all your fedora boxes automatically get the changes.
2. Put a cron job on the fedora boxes, which downloads Home.xml from a pre-specified location: a website you control, an ftp server, your main computer, etc.
3. Use port forwarding to allow SSH connections to your fedora boxes.

Comment: Hope it helps. Just shout if you need any more info any any of the options

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it by myself but I assume you could reach your goal by using path substitutions in advancedsettings.xml.
Please see http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Path_substitution for details.